# django channels: how to restrict access to a chat room except certain two people?

Tags: django, django-channels

I'm building a chat app using Django channels. Now the app allow users to watch any chat rooms if they know the urls for them.

I wanna restrict access to each chat room except certain two people.
How do I realize that on Django channels?
How do I allow only certain users to access to a url on Django app in general?

Url for chat rooms in my chat app is following.

---

### url(r'^(?P[\w-]{,50})/$', views.chat_room, name='chat_room')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Django app (no channels for now) what you would do is first enforce authentication (using for instance the [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator) and then check `request.user` for any conditions that you want to satisfy. There are many ways to achieve this, but I guess the one I described is the easiest.

As for Django Channels, you will have to do something rather similar. For the sake of an example, let's say you are using `WebSockets`. What you can do is set a token that is sent in every 'subscribe' request, and then map that token to a user. If the mapping satisfies all your criteria (is a valid token that maps to one of the users that can access the endpoint) you add them to the group, otherwise you do not. [Here](http://www.machinalis.com/blog/jwt-django-channels/) is a guide for JWT tokens that you can use.

Comment: Sorry for delay replay and thank you for answering, your comment help me, but how do I retain the tokens for a user?

Comment: A token can be anything you use to authenticate the user with. In a standard Django setup you get a cookie. You can send that in your WebSocket subscription message (use HTTPS!). If you use a JWT token (or any other mechanism) you can store it in the localStorage).

Comment: Thank you, I found a python library "itsdangerous" for treating a token. I'm gonna use it.

Comment: Nice! I've also worked with that library and I really liked it.